# Fonts bug in terminal (Arch)

Tags: terminal, arch-linux, fonts, xfce

I' ve installed droid fonts, after that in terminal I see the word not well, someone is on another 
[image]

As you can see the problems are especially with 'm' and 'w'
What's the problem?

Comment: It looks like you selected the sans-serif variable-width version of the font... Can you try picking something like "Droid Sans Mono"? This kind of problems is expected when variable-width fonts are used as sans serif fonts, some terminal emulators may cope better with this, but monospaced fonts will always work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by removing the `ttf-droid` font:

```
sudo pacman -R ttf-droid
```

Comment: You could always have changed the terminal settings to use a monospace font...